# Should datastore entity always have parent

Tags: google-app-engine

One of the good thing of having parent for datastore entity is that, I can perform transaction on my entity.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions

However, I don't need to perform transaction on my entity.

I was wondering, is it OK to **NOT having** parent for my entity? As, this will make my code simpler and easy to maintain?

Is there any side effect of not having parent for an entity?

One of my concern of not having parent, is **eventually consistency**. After write operation, I want my read operation able to fetch the latest written value. I'm using `User.get_or_insert` to write (possible read), and `User.get_by_id` to read only.

I want after I execute `User.get_or_insert`, and next request `User.get_by_id` will return latest value. I was wondering, to achieve **strong consistency**, is parent key an important thingy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering, is it OK to **NOT having** parent for my entity?

Absolutely, yes, but you need to consider how you will be reading and writing your data so you don't run into any gotchas down the line.

If you don't have an ancestor, your queries will have only eventual consistency, so you may find some results that don't match your query.  Remember, you can also use cross entity group ('XG') transactions which can involve up to 5 entity groups (an entity without an ancestor defines its own entity group), which allows you some flexibility.

On the other hand, you can at any time still get strong consistency, using get-by-key, regardless of whether your entity has an ancestor.

Comment: Good answer, but it might be worth clarifying that your first sentence is answering the question as it's phrased in the question-body, and not the one in the title - which is unfortunately the opposite :) And cross-group transactions are now limited to 25 entity-groups, up from 5.

Comment: @Greg - Thanks, good spot!  I've added a quote to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you will be subject to eventual consistency: queries outside a transaction are not guaranteed to be consistent. If this doesn't bother you, then there is no reason to use parents.

Comment: If I use `User.get_or_insert` to write (possible read), and `User.get_by_id` to read, can it achieve strong consistency behaviour without parent?

Comment: Well, if you only access items by key, then yes you will always get the latest version. But are you sure you will never need to query a user by name, or iterate over users matching some criteria?